# Starting of Tomcat failed in Netbeans 7

Tags: tomcat7, netbeans-7

I am trying to run my application via Netbeans 7.0 on tomcat 7.0.11 (bundled with the Netbeans itself).

When I try to run the application I am getting the following error.

I have reinstalled everything many times but I am still getting same issues.

It runs properly first time and then if I stop the server and then try to start it again then it creates the problem. At times when I restart my PC it works and sometimes even restarting the PC does not work.

Below is the error stack from Netbeans 7.0

```
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Checking data source definitions for missing JDBC drivers...
Starting Tomcat process...
Waiting for Tomcat...
Starting of Tomcat failed.
E:\workspaces\netbeansws\myApp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:770: 
Deployment error:
Starting of Tomcat failed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:200)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor85.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 minutes 0 seconds)
```

Please help !

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking at the the Tomcat logs to find out what the specific error is.

Comment: Seedhead meant the Tomcat logs not the Netbeans logs